# Trying to use array method to help display message

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace my display message to instead of showing "too low", "correct", it will take it from the array function to help display my message. For example, "Your guess number 1 is 2 and it is too low", "Your guess number 2 is 30 and it is too high", something like that, but I'm not sure how to implement the array function into my RandomNumber() function.

```
function RandomNumber()
        {
            var guessed = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
            var value4 = document.getElementById("guess").value;
            
           count++; 
            
           if (guessed==value4){
               document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML +="correct<br/>"
           }
            else if(guessed>value4){
                document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML +="wrong <br/>"
            }
            else if(guessed<value4){
                document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML +="too low <br/>"
            }
            else if(guessed>value4){
                document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML +="too high <br/>"
            }
            if(count===5) {
                document.getElementById("correct").innerHTML +="max try <br/>"
                document.getElementById("guessing").disabled=true;
            }
        }
```

This is my array function which holds the output display I want

```
function getMessage(correctNumber, guess, guessNumber) 
{
    const highOrLow = guess > correctNumber?"too high.":"too low.";
    return `Your guess number ${guessNumber} is ${guess} and it is ${highOrLow}`;
}
```

Comment: So build a string `variable + "string" + otherVarible + "string"`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps or not, but I think that you can tweak it as follows,
remove all the if else statements and use the main if statement to print correct if the guess is equal to the value entered. Any other value will be incorrect, which can be handled with the else statement. The else statement calls the getMessage function which validates if the value is more or less than the correct value and returns the correct answer.

```js
let count = 0;
let value4;
let checkGuess = document.getElementById('checkGuess');
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  value4 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  checkGuess.addEventListener('click', RandomNumber);
});
let RandomNumber = () => {
  let guess = document.getElementById("textbox");
  let correct = document.getElementById("correct");
  //validate that the user entered a guess
  if (!guess.value) {
    alert('Please enter a guess');
    return;
  }
  count++;
  if (guess.value == value4) {
    correct.innerHTML += "correct<br/>"
  } else {
    correct.innerHTML += `${getMessage(guess.value)}<br>`;
  }
  if (count > 4) {
    correct.innerHTML += `max try, correct number is ${value4} <br/>`;
    guess.disabled = true;
  }
}

function getMessage(guess) {
  const highOrLow = guess > value4 ? "too high." : "too low.";
  return `Your guess number ${count} is ${guess} and it is ${highOrLow}`;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" name="textbox">
<button type="button" id="checkGuess">Check my guess!</button>
<div id="correct"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object to keep track of the state, especially the attempt count, because that also has to exist outside of the function (but is tied to a series of guesses).

Using OOP is a little more advanced and would be preferable, but this works too. Also note that this function does 2 things ( create a message and modify the guess-object, which is frowned upon ). Finally your code isn't generating a message for the correct answer, which may cause issues.

```js
let guess = { correct: 5, guess: 2, attempt: 0 };

function getMessage(guess) 
{
    const highOrLow = guess.guess > guess.correct?"too high.":"too low.";
    return `Your guess number ${++guess.attempt} is ${guess.guess} and it is ${highOrLow}`;
}

console.log( guess );
console.log( getMessage( guess ) );
console.log( guess );
guess.guess = 10;
console.log( getMessage( guess ) );
console.log( guess );
```